# Regular expression - check comma separated sub strings length

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expression. My input is a string with comma. I need to validate each sub string length is 3 which is split by comma. example: "em1,erg,123,enc" Here sub strings length is 3, so it is valid. If "em1,erg,123,ency", It should be invalid. How to validate in regular expression without any other code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^(?:[^,]{3},)*[^,]{3}$
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/WL8v3Ig8QO8wrYgi)

It consists of the following parts:

- `^` - beginning of the string
- `[^,]{3}` - exactly three characters not being a comma
- `,` - a comma
- `(?: ... )*` - the former wrapped in a (non-capturing) group followed by a `*`, which lets the contained pattern repeat (zero or more times).
- `[^,]{3}` - exactly three characters not being a comma. This is necessary to match the last three characters (which do not have a comma at the end)
- `$` - end of the string

Comment: and if I could another +1 one for making me discover the debuggex stuff ! :-)

Comment: I tested by Regex.Ismatch("em1,erg,123,ency","(?:[^,]{3},)*"); but it returns true. It should be false because 4th substring "ency" is 4 characters.

Comment: did you try the updated answer ? That first answer forgot to check the last value. @tessi updated his answer while I was commenting on that ;-)

Comment: btw, even a good tool as debuggex is nice, you can always check the [automata](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec03.pdf) and [regex](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec04.pdf) courses from the MIT, to understand more precisely what regexps are!

Comment: Looking at the documentation of IsMatch (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx) it only tests, if the RegEx is *contained* in the given string (which it is). Please try the updated RegEx (which tests for the beginning and the end of a string)

Comment: Nice. Javascript and C# takes number of lines. RE simply best. I should learn. ;-) TanQ